# ASP.NET - How to Get Result of a Data Binding in Code Before Binding?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, telerik

Assuming I have access to the object that would be databound, and the settings for the databinding DataField, FormatString, etc...

How would I programattically get the resulting string value of a databinding without actually databinding to a control?

Context:  This is in the overloaded InitializeCell event of a Telerik (Telerik.Web.UI) GridDropDownColumn that I am inheriting.  I want to cache the resulting string value, but I need the value before the normal databinding event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a separate database query early in the page life cycle (pre-init) and cache the value manually...

Comment: I should clarify, GridDropDownColumn represents a bound drop down column in a RadGrid (similar to GridView).  It wouldn't be appropriate to run a query inside of the initialize event of a dropdown column inside of the grid.  Also, it wouldn't give me access to the formatting or binding expression that the user using this column would have set.

Comment: I only ever used the Telerik controls once before. There is a mound of documentation on their site and I used their support in the past...